# Real Analysis Convergance

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If E is a subset of R, nonempty, and bounded, then there exists e in E such that supE-1 < e < supE.

I understand how this works for the subset with natural numbers because for the less than or equal to inequality, supE-1= e. However, I do not understand how this can work for all subsets of R where the inequality is strictly less than. 
I was thinking that this possibly had something to do with the Archimedean principle that for every x in R there is an n in N such that n>x. So there must be a real number between supE-1 and supE.

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Comment: Hint: if no $e \in E$ existed such that $\sup E - 1 < e \le \sup E$, then $\sup E - 1$ is an upper bound for $E$...

Comment: @TheoBendit Why did I not think of that lol. But question:  is there a difference because all the inequalities are strictly less than opposed to having one with the less than/equal to? It may just be a typo on the question, but I don't see how there would have to be an e if this were the natural numbers or integers. Either supE -1=e  or  e=supE  for those sets right?

Comment: If you don't have $\le$, and just $<$, then the result is false! For example, take a singleton set, e.g. $\{0\}$. Or, perhaps, take the set $[0, 1] \cup \{3\}$.

Comment: @TheoBendit That makes sense. I believe that the question has a typo. Thank you so much for your help!